# How to add strings before and after a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

### I would like to add some characters to the text output.

---

Here is my code:

```
thumbnailname = detail.xpath('.//h1/text()').get().replace(' ','-')
```

Here is my text output:

> Apple-iPhone-13-Pro-Max

---

**How do I get the following output?**

> My-Apple-iPhone-13-Pro-Max.jpg

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the strings:

```py
thumbnailname = "My-" + detail.xpath('.//h1/text()').get().replace(' ','-') + ".jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 easy ways to add strings before and after your string:

1. `yourstring = "start{0}end".format(yourstring)`
2. `yourstring = "start" + yourstring + "end"`

in your case:

```
thumbnailname = detail.xpath('.//h1/text()').get().replace(' ','-')
thumbnailname = "My-" + thumbnailname + ".jpg"
```

or

```
thumbnailname = "My-{0}.jpg".format(detail.xpath('.//h1/text()').get().replace(' ','-'))"
```